# Make octave-mode recognise the MATLAB command spmd

Tags: matlab, octave

The parallel toolbox for MATLAB has a command, `spmd`  (https://se.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/spmd.html), that octave-mode does not recognize. Note: I know how to make octave-mode recognize it as a keyword.

The problem is that MATLAB expects `spmd` to have a matching `end`, which confuses octave-mode that sees an "extra" `end`. In addition, the statements in between should be indented. E.g. like this:

```
parpool(3)
spmd
  q = magic(labindex + 2);
end
```

How can I make octave-mode treat `spmd` as per above?

The lisp snippet below makes octave-mode highlight `spmd` as if it was a keyword:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'octave-mode
                        '(("\\<spmd\\>". font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

Update: Clarified intention of workaround snippet above.

Update 2: Using Stefan's workaround partially solves the issue. The `end` is now matched to `spmd`, although indentation is to large for some reason. See below for an example of the result, where the statements

```
      while false
        1;             # The expected amount of indentation
      end

      spmd
          1;           # Twice the expected amount of indentation
      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `font-lock-add-keywords` doesn't really make "octave-mode treat spmd as a keyword", it just *highlights* it as such.

I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request support for this new syntax.

In the mean time, you can hack your way around with something like:

```
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook #'my-octave-grammar-extend)
(defun my-octave-grammar-extend ()
  (unless (assoc "spmd" smie-grammar)
    (push (cons "spmd" (cdr (assoc "while" smie-grammar)))
          smie-grammar)))
```

which should at least make `spmd` match with `end` (and vice-versa) and hopefully make indentation less confused.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear regarding why I mentioned font-lock-add-keywords.  I had only added that part as a partial workaround to get highlighting of spmd.

Comment: I tried the workaround above, and it does make octave-mode match the spdm with it's 'end', which is a significant improvement.
However, it does result in twice as much indentation compared to a 'while ... end'.  I'll update my question with an example of what the result looks like for anyone who wishes to use this workaround.

Comment: Did you report the problem upstream?

Comment: Yes, it's done.